# Flyout does not show content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controls, mahapps.metro

I am using the Mah.MetroApps package for my WPF application, In the XAML-file I define the flyoutControl, which is activated when a button is clicked.
The problem is, that it shows the flyout without the content e.g. a textblock.

So am I doing something wrong here?

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
    <Controls:FlyoutsControl>
        <Controls:Flyout x:Name="ActiveUserFlyout" Header="Active Users" Position="Right" Width="300"  IsOpen="{Binding FlyoutIsOpen}"/>
        <TextBlock FontSize="30">Stackoverflow</TextBlock>
    </Controls:FlyoutsControl>
</Controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
```

Comment: Which bit doesn't work? `TextBlock` or `Controls:Flyout` also shouldn't `TextBlock` be inside `Controls:Flyout`?

Comment: The TextBlock, but as you mentioned the problem was that it wasn't inside 'Controls:Flyout'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the TextBlock inside the flyout e. g.

```
<controls:FlyoutsControl>
    <controls:Flyout x:Name="ActiveUserFlyout"
                     Width="300"
                     Header="Active Users"
                     IsOpen="{Binding FlyoutIsOpen}"
                     Position="Right">
        <TextBlock FontSize="30">Stackoverflow</TextBlock>
    </controls:Flyout>
</controls:FlyoutsControl>
```